# Source request for Natural Deduction Exercises

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

What is your source of choice to get exercises on Natural Deduction? I already solved everything in Logic for Artificial Intelligence & Informational Technology and just about everything I could get my hands on online.

I am still not confident in my abilities to use ND properly, so I am looking for (preferably with answers / solved) exercises on Natural Deduction.

Anything, any book, any website, really anything you recommend would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul Teller's *Modern Formal Logic Primer* (now out of print) is freely available from his website, and answers to exercises can be downloaded. He uses a Fitch-style mode of laying out ND proofs. The book has many virtues, including explaining proof-strategies well, as I recall.

See http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu

Comment: Thank you so much! If you think of anything else - do PM me please. Thanks again mate!